# How to train any Hugging face transformer model (eg DistilBERT) for question answer from scratch using Tensorflow backend?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I want to understand how to train a hugging face transformer model (like BERT, DistilBERT, etc) for the question-answer system and TensorFlow as backend. Following is the logic that I am currently using (but I am not sure whether is it right approach):

1. I am using SQuAD v1.1 dataset.
2. In SQuAd dataset answer to any question is always present in context. So to put in simple words I am trying to predict start index and end index and answer.
3. I have transformed the dataset for the same purpose. I have added the start index and end index of on word level after performing tokenization. Here is how my dataset looks,
   [image]
4. Next I am encoded question and context as per hugging face docs guide and returing input_ids, attention_ids and token_type_ids; which will be used as input to model.

```
def tokenize(questions, contexts):
  input_ids, input_masks, input_segments = [],[],[]
  for question,context in tqdm_notebook(zip(questions, contexts)):
      inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(question,context, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512, pad_to_max_length=True,return_attention_mask=True, return_token_type_ids=True )
      input_ids.append(inputs['input_ids'])
      input_masks.append(inputs['attention_mask'])
      input_segments.append(inputs['token_type_ids'])

  return [np.asarray(input_ids, dtype='int32'), np.asarray(input_masks, dtype='int32'), np.asarray(input_segments, dtype='int32')]
```

5. Finally I define a Keras model which takes this three input and predict two value, start and end word index of answer from given context.

```
input_ids_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(512,), name='input_token', dtype='int32')
input_masks_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(512,), name='masked_token', dtype='int32')
input_segment_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(512,), name='segment_token', dtype='int32')
embedding_layer = transformer_model({'inputs':input_ids_in,'attention_mask':input_masks_in,
                                     'token_type_ids':input_segment_in})[0]
X = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(embedding_layer)
X = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(X)

start_branch = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(X)
start_branch = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(start_branch)
start_branch_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='softmax', name='start_branch')(start_branch)

end_branch = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(X)
end_branch = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(end_branch)
end_branch_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='softmax', name='end_branch')(end_branch)


model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids_in, input_masks_in, input_segment_in], outputs = [start_branch_output, end_branch_output])
```

I am using last softmax layer with 512 units as it is my max no of words I my aim is to predict index dromit.